# Can syscall(SYS_gettid) block?

Tags: c, linux

My understanding is that some if not all syscalls can be blocking. Is this a blocking call? I want to obtain a unique thread id in a function that gets called repeatedly and is time-sensitive. I was going to do like so:

```
//header.h
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#ifdef SYS_gettid
#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)
#else
#define gettid() 0
#endif
```

```
//file.c
#include "header.h"
...
void function()
{
        pid_t thread = gettid();
        //Logic based on thread
        ...
}
```

Here function will get called repeatedly and cannot block. Perhaps I should use `pthread_self()` and `pthread_equal(t1, t2)`?
Thanks.

EDIT: I could equally well use either. I understand they do not provide the same return values, but the logic I will perform on the thread id is to compare it to a set of known thread ids to basically figure out who is calling this. I have both the gettid() return value and the pthread_self() reutrn value saved off.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why this would block. It's just retrieving a value from a kernel data structure, there's nothing it needs to wait for.

Comment: It's not a "blocking syscall", but remember that all syscalls are an opportunity for the scheduler to decide it's time to do something else. (of course, that can happen at any other time as well, but syscalls make it more likely)

Comment: any syscall can block, especially if the memory pressure on the kernel allocator is high

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `pthread_self`, mostly because it's portable and `syscall(SYS_gettid)` isn't, but also because typical implementations don't need to trap into the kernel at all.  For instance, on the machine where I'm typing this, there is a special hardware register called [`tpidr_el0`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-06/AArch64-Registers/TPIDR-EL0--EL0-Read-Write-Software-Thread-ID-Register) that stores a pointer to thread-specific data, and so `pthread_self` can be just three instructions, with no privilege level change required:

```
0000000000077870 <pthread_self>:
   77870:       d53bd040        mrs     x0, tpidr_el0
   77874:       d11e4000        sub     x0, x0, #0x790
   77878:       d65f03c0        ret
```

To be fair, a system call on this architecture is *also* just a handful of instructions, e.g.

```
00000000000a67c0 <getpid>:
   a67c0:       d503245f        bti     c
   a67c4:       d2801588        mov     x8, #0xac
   a67c8:       d4000001        svc     #0x0
   a67cc:       d65f03c0        ret
```

but an assembly dump of the syscall stub does not show the hundreds or even thousands of cycles worth of costs hiding behind that `svc` instruction.  If you're doing something frequent and time-sensitive, not trapping into the kernel can be a huge win.

I'd also recommend you think about reorganizing your code so that work comes in bigger batches and you don't *need* to ask "what thread am I on?" so often.  Operations not done at all are always fastest.

Comment: It might also be worth considering thread-local variables, especially if you can employ the initial-exec model.

Comment: @o11c I actually did consider that too. But, fortunately, I think I found an even better way that doesn't even make use of thread ids at all and that is just extra data passed in as a parameter that is currently unused, but would solve my issue.